# How to get offsetof() a private class-member?

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, c++11, c++14

I have a C++ class (`Scenario`) wrapped in a Python type:

```
struct PyScenario {
    PyObject_HEAD
    Scenario scen;
};
```

I'd like to expose some of the private members of `Scenario` to Python scripts -- without using the explicit getter/setter functions:

```
static PyMemberDef scenarioMembers[] {
    {
        (char *)"a",
        T_DOUBLE, offsetof(PyScenario, scen._a),
        "The a"
    },
    {
        (char *)"b",
        T_INT, offsetof(PyScenario, scen._b),
        "The b"
    },
    NULL
};
```

Unfortunately, when I compile the above, I get an error like: `'double Scenario::_a' is private within this context`.

I don't want to make the `_a` and `_b` public, so I tried declaring the `PyMemberDef` a `friend` of `Scenario`:

```
class Scenario {
#ifdef PY_MAJOR_VERSION
    friend   struct PyMemberDef;
#endif
private:
    double   _a;
    int      _b;
    ....
};
```

Unfortunately, that didn't help... What's the right way?

Comment: "I'd like to expose some of the private members of Scenario to Python scripts -- without using the explicit getter/setter functions:" - *Why*? Why wouldn't you want to use the getter functions to get data from the object? That makes no sense to me.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Presumably they're trying to take advantage of `PyMemberDef`'s ability to generate accessors for simple values for them, rather than having to write custom functions for use with the somewhat more complicated/powerful `PyGetSetDef` approach to accessors. CPython is mostly C++-blind, so it can't use member functions directly, meaning they'd have to write wrappers to call the member function.

Comment: Thank you, @ShadowRanger. That's correct - I want the speed and the simplicity of direct access to the fields of standard scalar types, yes.

Comment: @MikhailT.: I'll note, while it's obviously more complex to write the `GetSet` descriptors vs. the `Member`, speed-wise, they should be roughly equivalent; `Member`s are just a special case of descriptors where the accessor functions are written for you; they're not faster in general (except possibly by an accident of using shared hot code paths).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental problem with what you're doing is that the initializer for a (presumably) global variable is in the global context. The initializer is not a part of a class nor a component of a function, so it can't be the friend of anything.

You should make the variable a function-`static` variable. And the function that contains the variable can be the friend of the class.

```
PyMemberDef *PyMemberInitializers()
{
    static PyMemberDef scenarioMembers[] {
        {
            (char *)"a",
            T_DOUBLE, offsetof(PyScenario, scen._a),
            "The a"
        },
        {
            (char *)"b",
            T_INT, offsetof(PyScenario, scen._b),
            "The b"
        },
        NULL
    };

    return scenarioMembers;
}
```

Comment: Well, this would likely work, but the [C++ manual](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) claims, beginning with C++11 (which I use), types can already be "friends" -- not just functions/classes... Am I misreading it?

Comment: @MikhailT.: "*types can already be "friends" -- not just functions/classes...*" Classes *are* types. And no, you can't declare `int` a friend. And my point is that friendship and access is about where the code the code that's accessing the member is. Code in a braced-init-list does not gain any additional rights to access members of a type. Code inside of a function gains the access rights of the function. Code inside a class definition gains the access rights of the class. Code in a braced-init-list has the access rights of the location where that code lives, nothing more.

Comment: But then, what does the 4th section [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) mean? I thought, by declaring the `PyMemberDef` a friend, I'm allowing exactly the usage I'm trying for...

Comment: @MikhailT.: `friend T;` is merely shorthand for `friend class/struct/union T;`, as clearly stated in that section. My point is this: if `X` is a friend of `Y`, that means that the members and definitions *within `X`* can access `Y`'s privates. An initializer that is applied to an object of type `X` is not "within `X`" and therefore doesn't count.